# Expandable Collapse TableView fix row to top

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I have expandable-collapse tableView. I can fix row to top when i open it but the problem is when i close the row that opened on the top, it is returning to previous location. I want to keep that row on top even it is closed.

When i open it fixing the top
[image: When i open it fixing the top]

I want to do like that after i close it at top
[image: I want to do like that after i close it at top]

and this is my function giving error: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: 'Attempted to scroll the table view to an out-of-bounds row

```
 @objc private func hideSection(sender: UIButton) {
        let section = sender.tag
        let index = IndexPath(row: 0, section: section)
        
        func indexPathsForSection() -> [IndexPath] {
            var indexPaths = [IndexPath]()
            for row in 0..<self.tableViewData[section].count {
                indexPaths.append(IndexPath(row: row, section: section))
            }
            return indexPaths
        }
        
        tableViewContentOffset = tableView.contentOffset
        
        if self.hiddenSections.contains(section) {
            self.hiddenSections.remove(section)
            self.tableView.insertRows(at: indexPathsForSection(), with: .fade)
            
            if tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section) > 0 {
                tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .top, animated: true)
            }
            
        } else {
            self.hiddenSections.insert(section)
            self.tableView.deleteRows(at: indexPathsForSection(), with: .fade)
            
            tableView.scrollToRow(at: index, at: .top, animated: true)
            
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Using UITableViewDiffableDataSource can help avoid the issue of the tableView jumping around when adding or removing cells, holds its scroll position better by default.